# resolving session fixation bug fix in resin app server

Tags: resin, session-fixation

I am using resin app server
request.getSession.invalidate();reguest.getSession(true) is not working properly and its not resetting session ID while using Resin.

Also I am not able to use request.changeSessionId() as the resin version is not able to use JavaEE7 libraries.

Please share your views on how to resolve session fixation with Resin

Comment: That just resolves a myth in my head. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Resin 4.0.x doesn't implement Servlet 3.1 API.

Resin provides reuse-session-id configuration option that helps control session cookie behaviour.

http://caucho.com/resin-4.0/reference.xtp#session-config