# Cannot Reset JSESSIONID After Authentication

Tags: java, refresh, reset, jsessionid, resin

I'm trying to reset JSESSIONID after login, but I cannot. I have tried the following:

```
...
HttpSession ghostSession = request.getSession(false);
ghostSession.invalidate();
request.getSession(true);

...

// some more manipulations of the ghostSession here. 
...
```

But the JSESSIONID doesn't get reset. Do I miss anything here? Is that because the manipulation of `ghostSession` after it's invalidated is preventing the JSESSIONID being reset?

I'm using Resin 4.X as my web container BTW.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the insight from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31662809/resolving-session-fixation-bug-fix-in-resin-app-server/31681395), it's a Resin problem.

Basically doing the combination of

```
request.getSession(false).invalidate();
request.getSession(true);
```

will not trigger Resin to reset the JSESSIONID.

Also `HttpSession.changeSessionId()` is only supported since Servlet 3.1, and Resin 4.0.X doesn't support Servlet 3.1.

What I ended up doing is to adjust Resin's session handling. I.e. set `<reuse-session-id>` to false within `<session-config>`.

I hope this helps.